# button identification when mousedown event occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mousedown, identification

I have code adding some button dynamically and these button have mousedown event.
When i click button, mousedown function called.
I want to identify what button i click in this event function.
Button.Name property is limited string value.

Exactly i want lower code.

```
...
Button btnTest = new Button();
btnTest.identificationvalue="111.";
btnTest.MouseDown+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(deletec);
...
private void deletec(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    string idvalue=((Button)sender).identificationvalue;
    if ( idvalue== "111.")
    {

    }
    else if (idvalue == "110.")
    {

    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: So, what problem do you have with this code?

Comment: Button have these property? or Can i set property to button?

Comment: You can use Dictionary<Button, string> type member variable. Or you can use Button.Tag property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my interpretation of your question, you want each button to have a unique identifier which can be used to determine which button is assigned to `sender` in the `deletec` method. For this, I would use the `Button.Tag` property, which, as stated on the MSDN reference page ([Control.Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), "Gets or sets the object that contains data about the control." (**Edit:** this was suggested by [Won Hyoung Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4128809/won-hyoung-lee) in the comments while I was initially writing this answer.)

Another possibility would be to use the `Button.Text` property, although this would depend on the context of the application.

In addition, if this approach were to be taken, rather than using if-else statements, it would be cleaner to use a switch statement, i.e.:

```
switch (id)
{
    case 111:
        // do something
        break;
    case 112:
        // do something else
        break;
    ...
}
```